# CakePHP sessions expiring with `Security.level` set to low and the `Session.timeout` set to 12000

Tags: php, session, cakephp, session-timeout

My client is complaining that she posts a form and gets kicked to her login. I have the following code in `app/config/core.php`:

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '12000');
Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

Sessions should last 1,000 hours with these settings, right? So what else is going on?

I realize that the client might be reporting the bug to me incorrectly and that there may be other factors involved, but I'm not even sure what to ask her about.

Comment: Is it possible that you may need to tune PHP's session configuration as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to Internet Explorer. That's as far as I got; I just told my client to use a better browser. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

a few months ago I had the same problem. in my case I had few bugs in my code, so they kick me off. if you use requestAction, then check them first.

Comment: another possible problem is that IE doesn't save cookies from a subdomain with special characters. for example http://this.subdomainisok.com, but http://there_are-problems.withthissubdomain.com